# Determining $E|X^{n}|$ for $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $n$ odd.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $X \sim N(0,1)$. What is $E|X^{n}|$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ odd?

**Attempt:** Since $X = -X$ in distribution, we have that $(-X)^{n} = X^{n} = -X^{n}$ in distribution. Then

$$E|X^{n}| = E(X^{n})^{+} + E(X^{n})^{-} = EX^{n} = 0$$

since $X^{n} = -X^{n}$ in distribution.

But I have been given to understand that this is not true.

Comment: Since $|X^n|$ is _nonnegative_, indeed $P\{|X^n| > 0\} = 1$, does it not _surprise_ you at all that your argument gives that $E[|X^n| = 0$? Do you have to be _told_ that something is awry here?

Comment: You're right; in fact, that's a similar line of reasoning that led me to realize that I am wrong. But I haven't identified where I'm at fault.

Comment: The problem is this:  $$|X| = \begin{cases} X, & X \ge 0, \\ -X, & X < 0. \end{cases}$$  Your calculation is incorrect because $\mathrm{E}[|X^n|] = 2 \mathrm{E}[(X^n)^+]$.  The second term doesn't cancel with the first; i.e., $$\mathrm{E}[(X^n)^+] = \mathrm{E}[(X^n)^-]$$ using your notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value is
$$
E_n = E[|X|^{2n+1}] = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right)x^{2n+1} dx
$$using parity to get rid of the $\{x<0\}$ part.

As you know that $$
\frac d{dx} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right) = -x \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right)
$$
you can integrate by parts:
$$
E_n = \left[-2 \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right)x^{2n} \right]_0^\infty
+ 2\times 2n \int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right)x^{2n-1} dx
\\ = 2n E_{n-1}
$$
if $n\neq 0$ and if $n=0$:
$$
E_0 = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right)x dx
= \left[-2 \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right) \right]_0^\infty
\\=\sqrt \frac 2\pi
$$

and so:

$$
E_n = 2^n n! \sqrt \frac 2\pi
$$

Comment: Mistyping $E[X^{2n+1}]$ for $E[|X|^{2n+1}]$ when the OP's trouble is to confuse $|x|=x^++x^-$ with $x=x^+-x^-$, is something one should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are wrong:

$E[|X^n|]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|^np(x)\space dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}(-1)^nx^np(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}x^np(x)\space dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^np(x)\space dx-\int_{-\infty}^{0}x^np(x)dx$

Now if you let $x=-u$, you will have:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^np(x)\space dx-\int_{-\infty}^{0}x^np(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^np(x)\space dx-\int_{\infty}^{0}(-1)^nu^np(u)\space (-du)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^np(x)\space dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}u^np(u)\space du=2\int_{0}^{\infty}x^np(x)\space dx$

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the Gamma function, then there is a shorter way to calculate the moments:

First of all, by symmetry,

$$\mathbb{E}(|X|^{2k+1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^{2k+1} \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \, dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{\infty} x^{2k+1} \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \, dx.$$

Now substitute $y:= x^2/2$, i.e. $dy/dx=x$:

$$\mathbb{E}(|X|^{2k+1}) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} 2^{k} \int_0^{\infty} y^{k} \exp(-y) \, dy = \frac{2^{k+1/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \underbrace{\Gamma \left( k+1 \right)}_{k!}.$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{E}(|X|^n) = \frac{2^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left( \frac{n-1}{2} \right)!$$

for any odd $n$.